# Get divisors of a number whose ratio is a prime number

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to get all divisors of any number (up to 10e9) whose ratio is a prime number.

> Consider all divisors of some integer n. Choose some of these divisors, then arrange them in a circle so that the ratio of any two adjacent numbers is a prime number.
> Find the maximum number of divisors of n you can choose, and find the appropriate arrangement.

For example:

```
input: 10
output: 1 2 10 5
```

2 = 1 * **2**; 10 = 2 * **5**; 5 = 1 * **5**

Also an output array must be a cycle (circle). Therefore ratio of first and last numbers must be a prime number.

I tried to find all divisors of given number and generate all possible permutations of them and check each permutation:

```py
from itertools import permutations

n = int(input())
d = list(filter(lambda x: not n % x, range(1, n + 1)))
for i in range(1, len(d)):
    print(list(permutations(d, i)))
    # check the permutation
```

But it's a bad solution because it works very long. Can anyone suggest an algorithm to solve my problem more effective?

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags, or any unrelated tags for that matter, to questions.

Comment: You may want to search for fast algorythms that do a prime factorization of your number, then construct whatever you want from those prime factors. Still haven't quite gotten from your problem statement what you are after ... maybe more examples with explanations will make that more clear.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I need to create a circle of divisors of given number. In that circle adjacent divisors must be obtained from each other by multiplication or division by a prime number.

Comment: Not always possible. For example, you can't do it with 36. You're trying to construct a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph of divisors, and such a cycle doesn't always exist.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I don't need to include all divisors of number in my output. (Only maximum possible amount).

Comment: Please give an example for the output. For examle [(1, 10), (2, 5), (5, 2)] for n=10??

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is coming up with a good algorithm. Having somebody suggest you an algorithm defeats the purpose.

Comment: Can you share a link to where the original problem is posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding a new answer because I thought of a very different process to get the divisor list.

Instead of focusing on the factors, I create a sequence of prime ratios (multiplications and divisions).  Given that we need to loop back to the initial value, each multiplicative ratio will have to eventually be followed by the corresponding division of the same ratio.  So we just need to find the right ordering of prime multiplications and divisions (using the number's prime factors).

For example the prime factors of 6 are 2 and 3 and the factors are 1,2,3, and 6. The ratios between factors will either be 2 or 3.  Starting from 1, we can have a sequence of ratios: x2, x3, /2, /3 which will produce the sequence of factors: 1, 2, 6, 3, 1. (last one is loopback to 1). This balances each xPrime with a corresponding /Prime ensuring that the loop is complete.

If we add a prime factor (5) and go to 30, the prime factors are 2, 3, and 5, the factors are now 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 10, 15 and 30.

When there are more than two prime factors, The ratios sequences can be recursively "stacked" on top of each prime (used as a baseline).  This means that a sequence of factors (e.g. 3,5 --> x3, x5, /3, /5) can stand on its own and return to the original value (1) but it can also start from a different baseline (e.g. 2) and will come back to it without producing any of the factors that it had from the 1 baseline:

```
from 1:   (x3, x5, /3, /5) --> 3, 15, 5,  1
from 2:   (x3, x5, /3, /5) --> 6, 30, 10, 2
```

- The basic sequence for 2 is `x2, /2`
- Stacking 3 and 5 over the x2 baseline, we would have:

  - `x2, <stack 3 and 5> , /2`
- The sequence for 3 and 5 is `x3, x5, /3, /5`
- giving: `x2, x3, x5, /3, /5 , /2`
- but the last division (/5) of the stacked sequence would produce a repeated factor because the sequence loops back to the baseline.
- So we swap the last division (/5) with the next one (/2):
- Giving: `x2, x3, x5, /3, /2, /5`
- resulting in the factors: `2, 6, 30, 10, 5, 1`

This also applies sequentially when there are 4 or more prime factors, by looping back to each prime and stacking the remaining factors on top of it (as a new unique baseline).

for repeated prime factors, the xP and /P can be repeated as long as xP and /P are not consecutive.  So, for 20 (2,2,5) the initial sequence (x2, x5, /2, /5) can be expanded to (x2, x2, x5, /2, /2, /5) giving factors (2, 4, 20, 10, 5, 1).  For 8 however (2,2,2) the sequence is (x2, /2) so we cannot repeat the ratios.

This is similar to the way combinations are built recursively by starting with each value (prime factor in this case) and adding the pattern of combinations from the remaining values

This will still need a prime factorization function:

```
def primeFactors(N):
    d = 2
    while d*d<=N:
        while N%d==0:
            yield d
            N //= d
        d += 1
    if N>1: yield N
```

The ratio sequence function is recursive and uses positive numbers to indicate mutiplications and negative numbers to indicate divisions (e.g. x2, x3, /2, /x --> [2, 3, -2, -3])

```
def getRatios(factors):
    rFactors = list(factors)       # repeatable prime factors
    uFactors = set(rFactors)       # unique prime factors
    ratios   = []                  # resulting sequence of ratios
    while uFactors:                # new baseline for each prime
        if not ratios:             # first multiplication            
            f = min(uFactors)
            ratios = [f,-f]        # positive = multiply, negative = divide
        else:                              # extend recursively
            fr = getRatios(rFactors)       # pattern over baseline
            if not fr: break
            fr.insert(-1,ratios.pop(-1))   # swap last divisions
            ratios.extend(fr)              # extend ratio sequence
            f = abs(ratios[-1])            # last used prime factor
        rFactors = [r for r in rFactors if r!=f] # remove last used prime
        uFactors.discard(f)                      #
    for i,f in enumerate(reversed(ratios),1-len(ratios)): # repeat primes
        i = -i
        if f<0 and ratios[i-1:i+1 or None] == [-f,f]: continue
        if f>0 and ratios[i:i+2 or None]   == [f,-f]: continue
        count = factors.count(abs(f))        
        if count > 1: ratios[i:i] = [f]*(count-1) # expand repeated prime
    return ratios
```

The final result is obtained by applying the ratios sequentially starting from a baseline of 1 (excluding the last division because we only need to see 1 once:

```
def factorCircle2(N):
    ratios = getRatios([*primeFactors(N)])  # get ratio sequence
    result = [1]                         # startfactors at 1
    for r in ratios[:-1]:                # apply ratios to get factors
        result.append(result[-1]*r if r>0 else result[-1]//-r)
    return result
```

Output:

```
print(factorCircle2(10))    # [1, 2, 10, 5]                # 4 of 4 factors
print(factorCircle2(30))    # [1, 2, 6, 30, 10, 5, 15, 3]  # 8 of 8
print(factorCircle2(512))   # [1, 2]                       # 2 of 10 
print(factorCircle2(660))   
# [1, 2, 4, 12, 60, 660, 132, 44, 220, 20, 10, 30, 330, 110, 22, 
   66, 6, 3, 15, 165, 33, 11, 55, 5]                       # 24 of 24
print(factorCircle2(60060)) 
# [1, 2, 4, 12, 60, 420, 4620, 60060, 5460, 780, 8580, 660, 132, 924, 
   12012, 1716, 156, 1092, 84, 28, 140, 1540, 20020, 1820, 364, 4004,
   308, 44, 220, 2860, 572, 52, 260, 20, 10, 30, 210, 2310, 30030, 
   2730, 390, 4290, 330, 110, 770, 10010, 1430, 130, 910, 70, 14, 42, 
   462, 6006, 546, 182, 2002, 154, 22, 66, 858, 286, 26, 78, 6, 3, 15,
   105, 1155, 15015, 1365, 195, 2145, 165, 33, 231, 3003, 429, 39, 273, 
   21, 7, 35, 385, 5005, 455, 91, 1001, 77, 11, 55, 715, 143, 13, 65, 
   5]   # 96 of 96 factors
```

*After doing some testing I believe this covers all cases and the performance is much much better than the graph based solution.*

*Note: I found another issue with the adjusted code which sometimes prevents it from reaching the maximum cycle length when there are repeated primes*

Comment: Thanks, it's good solution.

Comment: I found a rather simple construction, but I am not sure if it is optimal. The number is prime decomposed. If at least one of the prime multiplicity is odd, the chain is complete, i.e. optimal. The problem is when all multiplicities are even. In this case, the algorithm lead to a *loss* equal to `alpha - 1`, when  `alpha` is the minimum multiplicity.

Comment: I figured out the logic for repeated primes and adjusted the code accordingly.  I'm not sure about your even/odd condition though (doesn't seem to cover all cases).  See the explanation on repeated primes processing I added to the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't seem to cover all cases*? And what do you mean by *which sometimes prevents it from reaching the maximum cycle length *? When all multiplicities are even (e.g. n = 36, max length = 8, for 9 divisors), you cannot include all divisors in the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by converting it to finding the longest path in a graph (although that is NP-Hard and may not be much faster).

The graph would be formed of nodes corresponding to the factors and edges that link nodes with a prime ratio between factors.

You will first need a function that give you all the prime factors of a number (including repeating primes):

```
def primeFactors(N):
    d = 2
    while d*d<=N:
        while N%d==0:
            yield d
            N //= d
        d += 1
    if N>1: yield N
```

You can then combine all these prime factors into a dictionary of factors where the value is a set of other factors that are at a prime ratio from each factor {factor:{factor with prime ratio}..} .  This will be your graph.

```
def factorGraph(N):
    primes  = list(primeFactors(N))
    factors = {1:set(primes)}
    for p in primes:
        factors.update({p*f:set() for f in factors})
    for p in set(primes):
        for f in factors:
            if f%p==0:
                factors[f].add(f//p)
                factors[f//p].add(f)
    return factors
```

Then use a recursive function to find the longest circular path from a starting factor to a given target node (starting with the related nodes of the target node itself).  The function must not use the same factor more than once so it pushes down a set of visited nodes (seen) to exclude them from the deeper search.

```
def longestCircle(graph,target,fromFactor=0,seen=set()):
    longest = []
    remaining = graph[fromFactor or target] - seen  # eligible next factors
    for factor in remaining:                        # Try each factor
        path = [factor]                             # form a path
        if factor != target:                        # must reach target
            path += longestCircle(graph,target,factor,seen|{factor})
        if path[-1]==target and len(path)>=len(longest): 
            longest = path                          # keep longest path
            if len(path)==len(graph): return path   # all factors used
    return longest
```

Finally, the longest circular path of factors will be the one with the most elements.

```
def factorCircle(N):
    graph = factorGraph(N)
    return max((longestCircle(graph,first) for first in graph),key=len)
```

*Note that this is checking from every possible starting factor in case a longer path skips one of the factors but it is likely that that 1 is always in the cycle so that may be overkill Returning longestCircle(graph,1) is probably enough but I don't have time to prove that it is (or is not).*

output:

```
print(factorCircle(10))  # [5, 10, 2, 1]               # 4 of 4 factors
print(factorCircle(30))  # [5, 15, 30, 10, 2, 6, 3, 1] # 8 of 8
print(factorCircle(512)) # [2, 1]                      # 2 of 10
print(factorCircle(660)) 
# [5, 15, 30, 6, 66, 22, 110, 220, 44, 4, 2, 10, 20, 60, 12,
   132, 660, 330, 165, 55, 11, 33, 3, 1]               # 24 of 24
```

Comment: Your solution works fine only for small numbers but thanks anyway.